# How can I use SSL with NuSOAP?

Tags: php, ssl, nusoap

I'm using the NuSOAP library with PHP.  How can I start using SSL?

Can I simply replace 'http' with 'https', or do I need to generate keys for NuSOAP?

Server code:

```
$server = new soap_server();

$server->register("GetMaxFileUpload",
                      array('sLanguage' => 'tns:string'),
                      array('return' => 'tns:getmaxfileupload'),
                      'urn:datalist', 'urn:datalist#GetMaxFileUpload');

$server->service(file_get_contents("php://input"));
```

Client code:

```
$client = new    nusoap_client($GLOBALS['gsSOAPserver'].'webservice/uploadmaxfilesize.php');

$sUploadlimit= $client->call('GetMaxFileUpload', array('sLanguage'=>$GLOBALS['gsLanguage']));
```

Comment: "Can I simply replace 'http' with 'https', " i know one way to find out ---- try it

Comment: My server doesn't currently support https.  It will soon.  This is part of a large software upgrade and server transition project.

Comment: if the server has openssl installed you are basically set.

Comment: Are you running the server or client?

Comment: OK rtfm, hope it works.  I'm running both server and client.